# Writing with dd in an NFS mount point

Tags: linux, nfs, dd

I am trying the following:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/sda1 of=/mnt/nfs/l bs=1M
```

It fails:

```
dd: opening `/mnt/nfs/l': Permission denied
```

However, normal file creation and writing with "cat" works.

What could be the cause for this?

Linux, NFS v3

Comment: Did you use 'sudo' when testing normal file creation and writing with cat?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most likely cause is root squashing.  This is a server option that changes the the requester for file operations when coming from the clients root user.  Commonly the root user is changed to nobody on the server.

If /mnt/nfs is exported from the server with root squashing then the user nobody will need to have permissions to write to the directory.